# Best practice for handling onError and continuing processing

Tags: rx-java

I am new to RxJava but I am integrating it into a project that I am working on to help me learn it. I have run into a question about best practices.

I have a question about how to handle `onError` from preventing the stopping of the `Observable` processing.

Here is the setup:

I have a list of userIds for each one I would like to do 2 or more network requests. If any of the network requests fails for the userid then that userid won't be updated and can be skipped.  This should not prevent the other userids from being processed.  I do have a solution, but it involves nested subscribes (see second block of code).  One problem I do see is, if each call fails there is no way to short circuit and stop the remaining from hitting a network resource even after detecting a certain threshold number have failed.

Is there a better way to do this?

**In traditional code:**

```java
List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
for (String userId : userIds) {
    try {
        String info = getInfo(userId);  // can throw an GetInfoException
        String otherInfo = getOtherInfo(userId);  // can throw an GetOtherInfoException
        results.add(info + ", " + otherInfo);
    } catch (GetInfoException e) {
        log.error(e);
    } catch (GetOtherInfoException e) {
        log.error(e);
    }
}
```

**PROBLEM:**

**Pseudocode:**

```
userid -> network requests -> result 
1 -> a, b -> onNext(1[a ,b])
2 -> a, onError -> onError
3 -> a, b -> onNext(3[a, b])
4 -> a, b -> onNext(4[a, b])
```

The following is a working example of a list of userIds and for each 2 requests for info.  If you run it you will see that it will fail (see below the source code)

```java
import rx.Observable;
import rx.Observable.OnSubscribeFunc;
import rx.Observer;
import rx.Subscription;
import rx.subscriptions.Subscriptions;
import rx.util.functions.Action0;
import rx.util.functions.Action1;
import rx.util.functions.Func1;

public class TestMergeDelayError {

    public static Observable<String> getUserIds() {
        return Observable.from(new String[]{"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"});
    }

    public static Observable<String> getInfo(final String prefix, final String integer, final String errorNumber) {
        Observable<String> observable = Observable.create(new OnSubscribeFunc<String>() {

            public Subscription onSubscribe(Observer<? super String> t1) {
                if (integer.contains(errorNumber)) {
                    t1.onError(new Exception());
                } else {
                    t1.onNext(prefix + integer);
                    t1.onCompleted();
                }
                return Subscriptions.empty();
            }
        });
        return observable;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Observable<String> userIdObservable = getUserIds();
        Observable<String> t = userIdObservable.flatMap(new Func1<String, Observable<String>>() {

            public Observable<String> call(final String t1) {
                Observable<String> info1 = getInfo("1::: ", t1, "2");
                Observable<String> info2 = getInfo("2::: ",t1, "3");
                return Observable.mergeDelayError(info1, info2);
            }
        });

        t.subscribe(new Action1<String>() {

            public void call(String t1) {
                System.out.println(t1);
            }
        }, new Action1<Throwable>() {

            public void call(Throwable t1) {
                t1.printStackTrace();
            }
        },
        new Action0(){

            public void call() {
                System.out.println("onComplete");
            }

        });
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
1::: 1
2::: 1
2::: 2
java.lang.Exception
        at TestMergeDelayError$1.onSubscribe(TestMergeDelayError.java:32)
        at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:241)
        at rx.operators.OperationMergeDelayError$MergeDelayErrorObservable$ParentObserver.onNext(OperationMergeDelayError.java:266)
        at rx.operators.OperationMergeDelayError$MergeDelayErrorObservable$ParentObserver.onNext(OperationMergeDelayError.java:210)
        at rx.operators.OperationMergeDelayError$2.onSubscribe(OperationMergeDelayError.java:77)
        at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:241)
        at rx.operators.OperationMergeDelayError$MergeDelayErrorObservable.onSubscribe(OperationMergeDelayError.java:171)
        at rx.operators.OperationMergeDelayError$1.onSubscribe(OperationMergeDelayError.java:64)
        at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:241)
        at rx.operators.OperationMerge$MergeObservable$ParentObserver.onNext(OperationMerge.java:164)
        at rx.operators.OperationMerge$MergeObservable$ParentObserver.onNext(OperationMerge.java:116)
        at rx.operators.OperationMap$MapObservable$1.onNext(OperationMap.java:105)
        at rx.operators.SafeObserver.onNext(SafeObserver.java:102)
        at rx.operators.OperationToObservableIterable$ToObservableIterable.onSubscribe(OperationToObservableIterable.java:94)
        at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:241)
        at rx.operators.OperationMap$MapObservable.onSubscribe(OperationMap.java:102)
        at rx.operators.OperationMap$2.onSubscribe(OperationMap.java:76)
        at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:241)
        at rx.operators.OperationMerge$MergeObservable.onSubscribe(OperationMerge.java:106)
        at rx.operators.OperationMerge$1.onSubscribe(OperationMerge.java:56)
        at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:241)
        at rx.Observable.protectivelyWrapAndSubscribe(Observable.java:320)
        at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:483)
```

**Nested Subscribe Solution:**

```java
import rx.Observable;
import rx.Observable.OnSubscribeFunc;
import rx.Observer;
import rx.Subscription;
import rx.subscriptions.Subscriptions;
import rx.util.functions.Action0;
import rx.util.functions.Action1;
import rx.util.functions.Func1;

public class TestMergeDelayError {

    public static Observable<String> getUserIds() {
        return Observable.from(new String[]{"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"});
    }

    public static Observable<String> getInfo(final String prefix, final String integer, final String errorNumber) {
        Observable<String> observable = Observable.create(new OnSubscribeFunc<String>() {

            public Subscription onSubscribe(Observer<? super String> t1) {
                if (integer.contains(errorNumber)) {
                    t1.onError(new Exception());
                } else {
                    t1.onNext(prefix + integer);
                    t1.onCompleted();
                }
                return Subscriptions.empty();
            }
        });
        return observable;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Observable<String> userIdObservable = getUserIds();
        userIdObservable.subscribe(new Action1<String>() {

            public void call(String t1) {
                Observable<String> info1 = getInfo("1::: ", t1, "2");
                Observable<String> info2 = getInfo("2::: ", t1, "3");
                Observable.merge(info1, info2).subscribe(new Action1<String>() {

                    public void call(String t1) {
                        System.out.println(t1);
                    }
                }, new Action1<Throwable>() {

                    public void call(Throwable t1) {
                        t1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                },
                        new Action0() {

                            public void call() {
                                System.out.println("onComplete");
                            }

                        });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
1::: 1
2::: 1
onComplete
java.lang.Exception
        at TestMergeDelayError$1.onSubscribe(TestMergeDelayError.java:28)
        at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:241)
        at rx.operators.OperationMerge$MergeObservable$ParentObserver.onNext(OperationMerge.java:164)
        at rx.operators.OperationMerge$MergeObservable$ParentObserver.onNext(OperationMerge.java:116)
        at rx.operators.OperationToObservableIterable$ToObservableIterable.onSubscribe(OperationToObservableIterable.java:94)
        at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:241)
        at rx.operators.OperationMerge$MergeObservable.onSubscribe(OperationMerge.java:106)
        at rx.operators.OperationMerge$1.onSubscribe(OperationMerge.java:56)
        at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:241)
        at rx.Observable.protectivelyWrapAndSubscribe(Observable.java:320)
        at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:483)
        at TestMergeDelayError$2.call(TestMergeDelayError.java:47)
        at TestMergeDelayError$2.call(TestMergeDelayError.java:42)
        at rx.Observable$2.onNext(Observable.java:381)
        at rx.operators.SafeObserver.onNext(SafeObserver.java:102)
        at rx.operators.OperationToObservableIterable$ToObservableIterable.onSubscribe(OperationToObservableIterable.java:94)
        at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:241)
        at rx.Observable.protectivelyWrapAndSubscribe(Observable.java:320)
        at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:367)
        at TestMergeDelayError.main(TestMergeDelayError.java:42)
1::: 3
java.lang.Exception
        at TestMergeDelayError$1.onSubscribe(TestMergeDelayError.java:28)
        at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:241)
        at rx.operators.OperationMerge$MergeObservable$ParentObserver.onNext(OperationMerge.java:164)
        at rx.operators.OperationMerge$MergeObservable$ParentObserver.onNext(OperationMerge.java:116)
        at rx.operators.OperationToObservableIterable$ToObservableIterable.onSubscribe(OperationToObservableIterable.java:94)
        at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:241)
        at rx.operators.OperationMerge$MergeObservable.onSubscribe(OperationMerge.java:106)
        at rx.operators.OperationMerge$1.onSubscribe(OperationMerge.java:56)
        at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:241)
        at rx.Observable.protectivelyWrapAndSubscribe(Observable.java:320)
        at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:483)
        at TestMergeDelayError$2.call(TestMergeDelayError.java:47)
        at TestMergeDelayError$2.call(TestMergeDelayError.java:42)
        at rx.Observable$2.onNext(Observable.java:381)
        at rx.operators.SafeObserver.onNext(SafeObserver.java:102)
        at rx.operators.OperationToObservableIterable$ToObservableIterable.onSubscribe(OperationToObservableIterable.java:94)
        at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:241)
        at rx.Observable.protectivelyWrapAndSubscribe(Observable.java:320)
        at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:367)
        at TestMergeDelayError.main(TestMergeDelayError.java:42)
1::: 4
2::: 4
onComplete
1::: 5
2::: 5
onComplete
1::: 6
2::: 6
onComplete
```

As you can see only the individual userids that failed stopped their individual processing but the rest of the userids were processed.

Just looking for advice, see if this solution makes sense and if not what the best practice is.

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: I think you're missing some types.  You don't really want an Observable of string; you want an observable of (sucessfulElement | unsuccessfulElement), and you want to do something interesting with the successes and something else with those failures.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The best practice is to use [mergeDelayError( )](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/merge.html) that combine multiple Observables into one, allowing error-free Observables to continue before propagating errors.

`mergeDelayError` behaves much like `merge`. The exception is when one of the Observables being merged terminates with an onError notification. If this happens with merge, the merged Observable will immediately issue an onError notification and terminate. mergeDelayError, on the other hand, will hold off on reporting the error until it has given any other non-error-producing Observables that it is merging a chance to finish emitting their items, and it will emit those itself, and will only terminate with an onError notification when all of the other merged Observables have finished.

Comment: what I don't want the observable to finish, ever? I don't think this reply the original question, it assume all the observable involved terminates and that it's ok to delay an error.

Comment: Agree with Daniele, this is an explanation of mergeDelayError(), not an answer to the question

Comment: this is not the best practice but just one of the ways of handling, other here https://medium.com/@jagsaund/5-not-so-obvious-things-about-rxjava-c388bd19efbc

Answer (score 18):

Since you want to ignore the error, you can try `onErrorResumeNext(Observable.<String>empty());`. For example,

```
Observable<String> info1 = getInfo("1::: ", t1, "2").onErrorResumeNext(Observable.<String>empty());
Observable<String> info2 = getInfo("2::: ", t1, "3").onErrorResumeNext(Observable.<String>empty());
return Observable.merge(info1, info2);
```

Comment: and if I don't want to ignore the error (aka = handle in in onError callback) but still keep processing the next events?

Comment: ^ Then subscribe again, in onError

Answer (score 1):

As a Rx newbie, I was also searching for a simple answer to process exceptions separately and continue processing next event but could not find answers
to what @Daniele Segato was asking. Here is one solution where you don't have control:

Above examples assume you have control over observables i.e., one way is to delay errors to the end using mergeDelayError OR return a known empty event Observable for every event as Observable separately using merge.

If it is a source event error, you can use lift to create another observable that basically processes the value of current Observable gracefully. SimpleErrorEmitter class simulates an unbounded stream that can fail sometimes.

```
Observable.create(new SimpleErrorEmitter())
        // transform errors to write to error stream
        .lift(new SuppressError<Integer>(System.err::println))
        .doOnNext(System.out::println)  // and everything else to console
        .subscribe();


class SimpleErrorEmitter implements OnSubscribe<Integer> {
@Override
public void call(Subscriber<? super Integer> subscriber) {
    subscriber.onNext(1);
    subscriber.onNext(2);

    subscriber.onError(new FooException());

    subscriber.onNext(3);
    subscriber.onNext(4);

    subscriber.onCompleted();
}

class SuppressError<T> implements Operator<T, T> {
final Action1<Throwable> onError;
public SuppressError(Action1<Throwable> onError) {
    this.onError = onError;
}
@Override
public Subscriber<? super T> call(Subscriber<? super T> t1) {
    return new Subscriber<T>(t1) {
        @Override
        public void onNext(T t) {
            t1.onNext(t);
        }
        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) { // handle errors using a separate function
            onError.call(e);
        }
        @Override
        public void onCompleted() {
            t1.onCompleted();
        }
    };
}
```

If it is a subscriber processing error which can try/catch and continue gracefully

```
    Observable<Integer> justInts = justStrs.map((str) -> {
        try {
            return Integer.parseInt(str);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            return null;
        }
    });
```

I am still trying to find a simple way to just retry or delay try the failed event and continue from next.

```
    Observable<String> justStrs = Observable
            .just("1", "2", "three", "4", "5")  // or an unbounded stream
            // both these retrying from beginning 
            // when you delay or retry, if they are of known exception type
            .retryWhen(ex -> ex.flatMap(eachex -> {
                // for example, if it is a socket or timeout type of exception, try delaying it or retrying it
                if (eachex instanceof RuntimeException) {
                    return Observable.timer(1L, TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS, Schedulers.immediate());
                }
                return Observable.error(eachex);
            }))
            // or simply retry 2 times
            .retry(2) // if it is the source problem, attempt retry
            .doOnError((ex) -> System.err.println("On Error:" + ex));
```

Reference: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rxjava/trm2n6S4FSc

Answer (score 1):

Looking at `Observable.flatMap`'s source:

```
return merge(map(func));
```

If you want all possible userids to be processed, you can go ahead with modified version of flatMap:

```
Observable.mergeDelayError(userIdObservable.map(userInfoFunc))
```

Further on, if you say:

> If any of the network requests fails for the userid then that userid
>   won't be updated and can be skipped

Then don't use:

```
return Observable.mergeDelayError(info1, info2);
```

Because this will cause both info1 and info2 to be requested even when one of them fails.

Rather go with:

```
return Observable.merge(info1, info2);
```

When info1 and info2 are subscribed to the same thread, they will run sequentially, so if info1 fails, info2 will never be requested.
Since info1 and info2 are I/O bounded, I assume you want to run them in parallel:

```
getInfo("1::: ", t1, "2").subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
getInfo("2::: ",t1, "3").subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
```

This should significantly speed up your processing

The whole code:

```
public class TestMergeDelayError {

    public static Observable<String> getUserIds() {
        return Observable.from(new String[]{"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"});
    }

    public static Observable<String> getInfo(final String prefix, final String integer, final String errorNumber) {
        return Observable.create(new OnSubscribeFunc<String>() {

            public Subscription onSubscribe(Observer<? super String> t1) {
                if (integer.contains(errorNumber)) {
                    t1.onError(new Exception());
                } else {
                    t1.onNext(prefix + integer);
                    t1.onCompleted();
                }
                return Subscriptions.empty();
            }
        })
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Observable<String> userIdObservable = getUserIds();
        Observable<String> t = Observable.mergeDelayError(userIdObservable.map(new Func1<String, Observable<String>>() {

            public Observable<String> call(final String t1) {
                Observable<String> info1 = getInfo("1::: ", t1, "2");
                Observable<String> info2 = getInfo("2::: ",t1, "3");
                return Observable.merge(info1, info2);
            }
        }));
        //rest is the same
    }
}
```